# DRF - filter list by DateField

Tags: python, date, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a **Ride** model:

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='rides_as_driver')
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name='rides_as_final_destination')
    leaving_time=models.TimeField()
    leaving_date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    num_of_spots=models.IntegerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name="rides_as_passenger")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToManyField(Destination, related_name='rides_as_middle_destination')
```

and I am trying to filter the `rides_as_driver` field by today's date:

```
def get(self, request):
        user=self.request.user
        driverRides = user.rides_as_driver.filter(leaving_time=datetime.date.today)
```

The filter line throws an exception, saying:

```
RemovedInDjango19Warning: Passing callable arguments to queryset is deprecated.
  value, lookups, used_joins = self.prepare_lookup_value(value, lookups, can_reuse, allow_joins)
```

I also tried with **get**: `driverRides = user.rides_as_driver.get(leaving_time=datetime.date.today)`, didn't work.

**How do I filter a list of objects by field value?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `leaving_time` is a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#timefield) which stores `datetime.time` values, while you are trying to filter by a  `datetime.datetime` object. You have `leaving_date` in your code which you should apparently filter by instead.

Second, the error says that you are passing a function (`datetime.date.today`) as a filter argument and [this is dropped in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9).

So what you want to do is:

```
driverRides = user.rides_as_driver.get(leaving_date=datetime.datetime.now().date())
```

Also check out [documentation on Time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) if you have to handle users from multiple time zones in your application.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried to change it to datetime.date.today(), it threw an exception saying "exception_value" - expected string or buffer

Comment: This is because `datetime.date.today()` returns `datetime.datetime` and [`TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#timefield) stores `datetime.time` values. You need `datetime.datetime.now().time()` instead.

Comment: now it throws exception saying "Ride matching query does not exist", but I do hve a ride with today's date. I think the problem is the datetime.datetime.now().time() is both the date and the time. the leaving_time field in Ride is of type DateField, I want to get the rides of today, doesn't matter the time.

Comment: Actually it is `leaving_time=models.TimeField()` in your code. You also have `leaving_date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)` which you have to filter by apparently if you want rides for a particular day. Both points still hold: you have to pass the _result_ of of the right function to your filter.

Comment: haha silly me, all this time I thought I compared leaving_date and I had it leaving_time by  mistake! it did work with datetime.date.today(), thanks!